# SQL não mantém novas gravações

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

Estou usando uma Service-based Database (.MDF) para salvar alguns dados de um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo. Entretanto, após eu fechar o aplicativo, os dados que foram inseridos na tabela desaparecem. Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|datadirectory|\Database2.mdf");
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO sistemas (nome, potnom, numcolun, colunpac, colunpcc, colunirrad, tempomed) VALUES ('"+ nome+ "','"+ potNom+"','"+ numcolun +"','"+ colunpac+"','" + colunpcc + "','" +colunirrad+"','" + tempoMed + "')";
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

O INSERT é executado corretamente, consigo fazer a consulta ao banco de dados se não fecho o aplicativo, entretanto, quando reinicio o aplicativo, a tabela volta vazia.

Comment: Veja se o arquivo .mdf não está sendo recriado quando inicializa o aplicativo.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, e foi corrigido com a solução do TonCunha abaixo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que as informações permaneçam no banco de dados .mdf, é necessário que você faça uma alteração nas propriedades do arquivo.

1. Clique com o botão direito sobre o banco de dados encontrado na aba *Solution Explorer*;
2. Vá em propriedades;
3. Na opção *Copy to Output Directory* selecione *Copy if newer*

[image: Alterando a propriedade do banco de dados]

Espero ter ajudado.